# Trying to SSH into an Amazon Ec2 instance - permission error?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to connect into AWS Ec2 server via mac Terminal but keep getting `Connection closed by xx.xx.xx.xx`.

Here's what happened last night: I was in the server and was deleting and uploading files from git. Everything was working fine until it kicked me out while I was trying to `sudo chmod -R 755`. Ever since I cannot get in from Terminal. Could this be a security issue, or could my key be damaged? Any help is appreciated.

Here are the steps that I took from terminal. `Mykey.pem` is located on my desktop so..

```
cd desktop
sudo ssh -i "myKey.pem" ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I keep getting an error

```
Warning: Identity file myKey.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.   
Connection closed by xx.xx.xx.xx
```

So I tried

```
chmod 400 mykey.pem
```

I keep getting an error

```
chmod: myKey.pem: No such file or directory
```

Has this happened to anyone? Is there a way to get in from terminal. By the way my instance is running normal and all my sites are up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use "sudo" to SSH. It might change your current working directory, and you don't need or even want to use root privileges to run a tool like that.
2. You're probably in the wrong folder. You don't say what OS you're running on, but on a Linux box, "desktop" and "Desktop" are not the same folder. On a Mac, they are. Check with "ls" to see that you can see the files you expect, other than that.

Comment: Sorry I'm on OS-X. And I know I'm in the right folder, I don't think it's local I strongly believe it's the server. Thanks

Comment: The message "chmod: myKey.pem: No such file or directory" strongly indicates that you're in the wrong directory. That's not server-side, that's on your machine.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but it is in the right directory. I can see the location of the pem file -Macintosh HD ▸ Users ▸ tuyasenff ▸ Desktop

Comment: What does the "pwd" command show when you think you're in the Desktop folder?

Answer (score 0):

It might not work as long as you keep that `.pem` file on your desktop.

If memory serves me well, these file must reside in a folder that is not group writable.

If you moved it to where it belongs...meaning in your `~/.ssh` folder it should work.

Comment: I'm not seeing ssh folder anywhere, it may have been deleted accidentally, if that's the case, this is the problem that's causing this. Let me work on this. thanks

Comment: so if you issue the _ls -la ~_ command you do not see a .ssh folder?